# Getting error: `Maximum execution time` when send Mail Queue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-queue

I using Laravel Mail Queue to send quick mail.

I have an error like:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in SendWelcomeEmail.php
>   (line 38)

Difficult to describe my error because I don't have experience with Laravel. So, I tried to record step by step what I did.

My problem is: when user click Send information, `Send Mail` is activated and it using too much time to complete this work. This affect to the user experience.

I expect an answer or another method to resolve my problem.

My demo was make with step by step:

**Step 1**:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test>php artisan queue:table
Migration created successfully!
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test>php artisan queue:failed-table
Migration created successfully!
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-test>php artisan migrate
Migrated: 2017_04_03_144759_create_jobs_table
Migrated: 2017_04_03_150557_create_failed_jobs_table
```

**Step 2**: update my .env file and setting email:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:beQGwYyUPOTMtkbzDhft7swh68UJW7RqwAGwhELUfLI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dongxanh
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=euEW12il

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yxpszfarmxoperew
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**Step 3**:

```
php artisan make:mail EmailCustomer
```

At function `__contruct()`:

```
protected $content;

public function __construct($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
}
```

Function `build()`:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.contact')
                ->with('content',$this->content);
}
```

**Step 4**: In `views/emails/contact.blade.php` is:

```
Name: {{ $content['name'] }} <br>
Title: {{ $content['title'] }} <br>
Email: {{ $content['email'] }} <br>
Phone number: {{ $content['phonenumber'] }} <br>
Body:

{{ $content['body'] }}
```

**Step 5**: Create Job `SendWelcomeEmail`:

```
php artisan make:job SendWelcomeEmail
```

It will create `SendWelcomeEmail.php` look like this:

```
use Mail;
use App\Mail\EmailCustomer;

class SendWelcomeEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $content;

    public function __construct($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(60);

        $receiverAddress = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $email = new EmailCustomer($content);
        Mail::to($receiverAddress)->queue($email);
    }
}
```

**Finally**: Send Job to Queue when user click submits form in `app\Http\Controllers\RegisterForm.php`:

```
public function storeCustomer(Request $request) {
    Customer::create($request->all());

    $content = [
        'name'=> $request->input('name'), 
        'title'=> $request->input('title'), 
        'email'=> $request->input('email'),
        'phonenumber'  => $request->input('phonenumber'),
        'body' => $request->input('body')
        ];

    dispatch(new SendWelcomeEmail($content));
    return view('partials.success-mail');
}
```

I run two commands:

```
php artisan serve

php artisan queue:work
```

And tested. It's show error like the question.

Comment: can you show your mail credentials? the `.env` file, it might be empty

Comment: @VladyslavStartsev I sent mail success with Laravel Mail. But I want using `Queue` to improve UX. You can see my `.env` file in updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use sleep here , Remove this to make queue work .

If need it try like this to increase time limit

```
 php artisan queue:work --timeout=0
```

Or you can use Task Schedule : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

Also Use `$this->content` not `$content`.

```
  $email = new EmailCustomer($content);
```

Comment: I have a question. It show an error like: `Undefined variable: content` at `Jobs\SendWelcomeEmail.php`. I declared variable `content` at: `app\Http\Controllers\RegisterForm.php`.

Comment: Use `$this->content` not `$content`.   Here `$email = new EmailCustomer($content);`

Comment: Thanks, @user2486, I see time to send very slow. I don't know the reason. When sent success, don't have any information or log in command: `php artisan queue:work --timeout=0`

Comment: It show be show log: `Start send emailEnd send email[2017-08-27 15:33:48] Processed: App\Jobs\SendWelcomeEmail` in command `php artisan queue:work --timeout=0`. But at my project, don't have any log show in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You missing this :

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```